# Converting X and Y coordinates from Mercator world map (square) image to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, mercator

I'm using the following JS to transform Latitude and Longitude to X and Y coordinates but now I need the contrary, transforming Latitude and Longitude to X and Y.

```
export const latLon2xy = (lat, lon, width, height) => {
    const x = Math.round((width * (180 + lon) / 360) % (1.5 * width))
    const rad = lat * Math.PI / 180
    const merc = 0.5 * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(rad)) / (1 - Math.sin(rad)))
    const y = Math.round((width * merc / (2 * Math.PI)))
    return {x: x, y: y}
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to reinvent the wheel here. Isn't there a javascript package with geospatial functions you could use?

Comment: This answer on SO might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13323592/2258

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that the proj4js library at http://proj4js.org/ does everything you need.

Comment: How would I use proj4() to translate x and y from a mercator projection image to longitude and latitude?

Comment: If you still need help after reading the fine manual and web searching I suggest you post a new question with more specifics about what you don't understand.